# Pulling out valid twitter names using re module in Python

Tags: python, regex

**1. Background info**

I have string which contains valid and invalid twitter user names as such:

> @moondra2017.org,@moondra,Python@moondra,@moondra_python

In the above string, **@moondra** and **@moondra_python** are valid usernames. The rest are not.

**1.1 Goal**

By using \b and/or \B as a part of regex pattern, I need to extract the valid usernames.

**P.S** I must use **\b** and/or **\B** as the part of the regex, that is part of this goal.

**2. My Failed Attempt**

```
import re

# (in)valid twitter user names
un1 = '@moondra2017.org' # invalid
un2 = '@moondra'        # << valid, we want this
un3 = 'Python@moondra'   # invalid
un4 = '@moondra_python' # << validwe want this

string23 = f'{un1},{un2},{un3},{un4}'

pattern = re.compile(r'(?:\B@\w+\b(?:[,])|\B@\w+\b)')  # ??
print('10:', re.findall(pattern, string23))  # line 10
```

**2.1 Observed**: The above code prints:

> 10: ['@moondra2017', '@moondra,', '@moondra_python']   # incorrect

**2.2 Expected:**

> 10: ['@moondra', '@moondra_python']   # correct

Comment: Does it mean you do not allow numbers? `pattern = re.compile(r'\B@[^\W\d]+\b') `? What is the matching criterion here? Or, do you mean you need to match the names up to `,` or end of string? `pattern = re.compile(r'\B@\w+\b(?![^,])')` (equivalent to `r'\B@\w+\b(?=,|$)'`)?

Comment: Hi, have you had time to check the solution below?

Comment: yes, i just checked your solution below. Pls see my comments to your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer assuming that the mentions are always in the format as shown above, comma-separated.

Then, to match the end of a mention, you need to use a comma boundary, `(?![^,])` or a less efficient but online tester friendly `(?=,|$)`.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\B@\w+\b(?![^,])')
pattern = re.compile(r'\B@\w+\b(?=,|$)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z6k4Ip/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JVybUA)

**Details**

- `\B` - a non-word boundary, there must be start of string or a non-word char immediately to the left of the current location
- `@` - a `@` char
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`)
- `\b` - a word boundary (the next char should be a non-word char or end of string)
- `(?![^,])` - the next char cannot be a char different from `,` (so it should be `,` or end of string).

Comment: Could you explain further, how does  the end of string $ satisfy (?![^,]) ?

Comment: @HKN `(?![^,])` matches a location that is not immediately followed with any char but a comma. If we are at the end of string, there can be no comma to the right, do you agree? That is why `(?![^,])` matches also the end of string. However, when we use regex testers, we use a single multiline string, and enable multiline mode for `$` using the `m` flag, and `(?![^,])` no longer works there because a newline can be matched with `[^,]` (=any char but a comma).